# Slack bot connection issue

Tags: python, slack

I can't connect my slackbot at all. I am using python.

There is no code involved because it says I cannot install the bot to the workspace.

Comment: Well, there must be *something* that you've done to raise that error. What commands did you run? What is the exact output? What does your code look like?

Comment: If someone came to you and said this exact thing, would you have any follow up questions for them or would you be able to assist them in troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-logging into slack. Everything should be saved. Worked for me when I had the same error.